# CKEDITOR Using getData()

Tags: javascript, html

How to get CKEDITOR first two `<p>` tag value using getData() method.

```
 var myContent = CKEDITOR.instances.Abody.getData();
```

output

```
<h1>title</h1> <p>paragraph 1</p> <p>paragraph 2</p>
```

But i need this `<p>` tag values like this.

```
var ph1 = paragraph 1
var ph2 = paragraph 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery then you can do something like this.

```
var myContent = CKEDITOR.instances.Abody.getData();
var paraList = $(myContent).find('p'); //paraList contains an array of paragraphs now.
$.each(paraList, function(i, node){ console.log( $(node).text());});
```